# T-SQL hierarchy from two tables to a single view

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, hierarchy

Hi there i am trying to make a view that holds the (mafia) hierarchy (up to 5 levels) from a single table for each and every user with an additional table to fill in the name of each user, this is the actual structure, i am using windows azure.

```
              [ 1 ]
             /  |  \
        [ 2 ]  [3]  [4]
        / |  \      |  \
     [5] [11] [12] [10]  [9]
      /\                   \
    [6] [8]                [15]
   /    /\                 /  \
[7]  [13] [14]         [17]    [16]
      |   |
     [19] [18]
     / \
  [20] [21]
```

These are the table's that i get the data from:

```
dbo.userFamily                  dbo.user
id | user_id | parent_id        id_user   |   name
------------------------        ------------------
1  | 2       | 1                1         |   Victor
2  | 3       | 1                2         |   Lucifer
3  | 4       | 1                3         |   Hellboy
4  | 11      | 2                4         |   Spiderman
5  | 12      | 2                5         |   Martin
6  | 10      | 4                6         |   Superwoman
7  | 9       | 4                7         |   Lex Luther
8  | 15      | 9                8         |   GodMaster
9  | 17      | 15               9         |   Demon
10 | 16      | 15               10        |   balou
11 | 6       | 5                11        |   Superman
12 | 8       | 5                12        |   xman
13 | 7       | 6                13        |   hulk
14 | 13      | 8                14        |   ironman
15 | 14      | 8                15        |   aquaman
16 | 19      | 13               16        |   wonderwoman
17 | 20      | 19               17        |   batman
18 | 21      | 19               18        |   robin
19 | 18      | 14               19        |   tiger
20 | 1       | NULL             20        |   oscar
```

And this is the part i have so far:

```
 SELECT dbo.UserFamily.id, dbo.UserFamily.user_id, dbo.[User].name AS capo,
 dbo.UserFamily.parent_id AS Capo_id, NULL AS underboss, 
 NULL AS underboss_id, NULL AS consigliere, NULL AS consigliere_id, 
 NULL AS godfather, NULL AS godfather_id
 FROM dbo.UserFamily 
 INNER JOIN dbo.[User] ON dbo.UserFamily.parent_id = dbo.[User].id_user
 ORDER BY dbo.UserFamily.user_id
```

this is the view i try to make (somehow user_id 1 is missing, what i think has to do with the fact there is no parent_id):

```
id | user_id | capo       | capo_id | underboss | underboss_id | etc.     | etc.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2       | Victor     | 1       | NULL      | NULL         | NULL
2  | 3       | Victor     | 1       | NULL      | NULL         | NULL
3  | 4       | Victor     | 1       | NULL      | NULL         | NULL
11 | 6       | Martin     | 5       | Lucifer   | 2            | Ewald
13 | 7       | Superwoman | 6       | Martin    | 5            | Lucifer  | 2
12 | 8       | Martin     | 5       | Martin    | 5            | Lucifer  | 2
```

But how do i get the other ones? Like the underboss etc. all the way up to the godfather? This is the family structure:

```
soldier (the user)
capo
underboss
consigliere
godfather
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive CTEs are the trick for building hierarchies like this. Here's a cool trick for rendering the hierarchy as a string:

```
;WITH cteBosses AS
(
    SELECT id_user, CAST(null AS VARCHAR(100)) AS parent_name, uf.parent_id, 
        name, 1 AS level, cast(name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS hierarchy
    FROM [dbo.user] u
    INNER JOIN dbo.userFamily uf ON u.id_user = uf.user_id
    WHERE uf.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.id_user, CAST(c.name AS VARCHAR(100)) AS parent_name, uf.parent_id, 
        u.name, c.level + 1 AS level, cast(c.hierarchy + ' -> ' + u.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS hierarchy
    FROM [dbo.user] u
    INNER JOIN dbo.userFamily uf ON u.id_user = uf.user_id
    INNER JOIN cteBosses c ON uf.parent_id = c.id_user
)
SELECT *
FROM cteBosses
ORDER BY hierarchy
```

This outputs:

```
id_user parent      name         parent_id   level  hierarchy
1       NULL        Victor       1           1      Victor
3       Victor      Hellboy      1           2      Victor -> Hellboy
2       Victor      Lucifer      2           2      Victor -> Lucifer
5       Lucifer     Martin       5           3      Victor -> Lucifer -> Martin
8       Martin      GodMaster    8           4      Victor -> Lucifer -> Martin -> GodMaster
13      GodMaster   hulk         13          5      Victor -> Lucifer -> Martin -> GodMaster -> hulk
19      hulk        tiger        19          6      Victor -> Lucifer -> Martin -> GodMaster -> hulk -> tiger
etc.
```

Read Steve Stedman's "Common Table Expressions Joes 2 Pros" for lots of great CTE examples like this. http://stevestedman.com/2013/06/cte-scope/

To generate the output you want, you can join the CTE to itself as many times as you need to, like this:

```
;WITH cteBosses AS
(
    SELECT id_user, CAST(null AS VARCHAR(100)) AS parent_name, uf.parent_id, 
        name, 1 AS level, cast(name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS hierarchy
    FROM [dbo.user] u
    INNER JOIN dbo.userFamily uf ON u.id_user = uf.user_id
    WHERE uf.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.id_user, CAST(c.name as VARCHAR(100)) AS parent_name, uf.parent_id, 
        u.name, c.level + 1 AS level, cast(c.hierarchy + ' -> ' + u.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS hierarchy
    FROM [dbo.user] u
    INNER JOIN dbo.userFamily uf ON u.id_user = uf.user_id
    INNER JOIN cteBosses c ON uf.parent_id = c.id_user
)
SELECT c1.id_user, c1.name, c2.id_user as capo_id, c2.name as capo, 
    c3.id_user as underboss_id, c3.name as underboss,
    c4.id_user as next_boss_id, c4.name as next_boss
FROM cteBosses c1
LEFT JOIN cteBosses c2 ON c1.parent_id = c2.id_user
LEFT JOIN cteBosses c3 ON c2.parent_id = c3.id_user
LEFT JOIN cteBosses c4 ON c3.parent_id = c4.id_user

id_user name        capo_id capo        underboss_id    underboss   next_boss_id    next_boss
1       Victor      NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
2       Lucifer     1       Victor      NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
3       Hellboy     1       Victor      NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
4       Spiderman   1       Victor      NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
9       Demon       4       Spiderman   1               Victor      NULL            NULL
10      balou       4       Spiderman   1               Victor      NULL            NULL
15      aquaman     9       Demon       4               Spiderman   1               Victor
16      wonderwoman 15      aquaman     9               Demon       4               Spiderman
17      batman      15      aquaman     9               Demon       4               Spiderman
```

To answer your follow up question about adding the CurrentPosition column, you can nest another CTE and use it for your EXISTS clause:

```
;WITH cteBosses AS
(
    SELECT id_user, CAST(null AS VARCHAR(100)) AS parent_name, uf.parent_id, 
        name, 1 AS level, cast(name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS hierarchy, id_user as top_parent, name as top_parent_name
    FROM [dbo.user] u
    INNER JOIN dbo.userFamily uf ON u.id_user = uf.user_id
    WHERE uf.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.id_user, CAST(c.name as VARCHAR(100)) AS parent_name, uf.parent_id, 
        u.name, c.level + 1 AS level, cast(c.hierarchy + ' -> ' + u.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS hierarchy,
        c.top_parent, c.top_parent_name
    FROM [dbo.user] u
    INNER JOIN dbo.userFamily uf ON u.id_user = uf.user_id
    INNER JOIN cteBosses c ON uf.parent_id = c.id_user
)
, cteHierarchy AS
(   
    SELECT c1.id_user, c1.name, c2.id_user as capo_id, c2.name as capo, 
        c3.id_user as underboss_id, c3.name as underboss,
        c4.id_user as next_boss_id, c4.name as next_boss    
    FROM cteBosses c1
    LEFT JOIN cteBosses c2 ON c1.parent_id = c2.id_user
    LEFT JOIN cteBosses c3 ON c2.parent_id = c3.id_user
    LEFT JOIN cteBosses c4 ON c3.parent_id = c4.id_user
)
select id_user, name, --*,  
case 
    when exists (select * from cteHierarchy cInner where next_boss = cOuter.name) then 'next_boss'
    when exists (select * from cteHierarchy cInner where underboss = cOuter.name) then 'underboss'
    when exists (select * from cteHierarchy cInner where capo = cOuter.name) then 'capo'
    else 'regular_dude'
end as CurrentPosition
from cteHierarchy cOuter

id_user   name      CurrentPosition
1         Victor    next_boss
4         Spiderman next_boss
9         Demon     underboss
```

You can keep adding levels of CTEs like this - a CTE can reference the CTEs that come before it (but not after). So you're basically giving a table alias to the query output and then using EXISTS to compute the CurrentPosition value.

Comment: thank you this is extremely cool, however when i try to work with you example, the bottom one, is get the following error: Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "parent_name" of recursive query "cteBosses".

Comment: @EwaldBos Try it now - for a recursive query, the anchor (top) and recursive (bottom) queries need to have identical data types in each column I modified the query to cast the parent_name column to a VARCHAR(100) in each query, so now the types match. (I had assumed a VARCHAR(25), but that doesn't match the definition for the name column in your table.)

Comment: yes it works perfectly, thank you so much for the explanation and the time you putted in.

Comment: i would like to add something to this query, how would i be able to get the max role for each user? As the above case 'Victor' and 'spiderman' would be a 'next_boss' and 'demon' would be an 'underboss'. To add this as a separate column 'CurentPosition' as example. (i am looking into the IF EXIST but not sure that is the right route to go).